# How can I replace all £ in a file with &pound; with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to replace all `£` symbols in a HTML file with `&pound;`. My regular expression does not seem to work.

Could you please help?

Comment: Show what you tried that didn't work so people can see what went wrong and help you?

Comment: You keep asking "What is the issue" in comments, but nobody can tell you since you haven't said what you did. Are you trying to do this in Vim? If so, _how_? Are you trying to do this using Perl? If so, _how_?

Comment: Sorry its mitake , before that i insert other comments and delete it . The problem is got sloved now

Comment: @Krish: Please make it a habit not to delete comments that others have replied to. Else, the reply comments would look out of place and context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
# File: convert.pl
no utf8; # its not required
while (<>) {
    s/(\xa3)/pound/g;
        print;
}
```

since `£` showed as `0xA3` on my hexdump.

But, so will

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
while (<>) {
    s/£/pound/g;
        print;
}
```

Just say

```
chmod a+x convert.pl
convert.pl yourfile.html > newfile.html
```

Answer (score 4):

You most probably forgot to:

```
use utf8;
```

Try the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

while (<DATA>) {
    s/£/&pound;/g;
    print
}

__END__
This is sample text with lots of £££!
50£ is better than 0£.
```

If you want to read from a file named `input` and write to a file named `output`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

open my $input,  '<', 'input'  or die $!;
open my $output, '>', 'output' or die $!;

binmode $input, ':utf8';

while (<$input>) {
    s/£/&pound;/g;
    print $output $_;
}
```

Comment: Why '&amp;pound;' and not just '&pound;' in the substitution? If you use &amp; it will come out as &pound; instead of £ in the browser.

Comment: @Lars Haugseth: The question was edited later to change `&amp;pound;` to `&pound;`. I have edited so. Thanks for letting me know. :-)

Comment: @Krish: Sorry, I did not understand what you are trying to do. Please explain.

Comment: That i can do find  and replace in vi editor . What is the issue

Comment: @Krish: I still do not understand what you are talking about. Yes, you can use `vi` to find and replace. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: s/(xa3) works for me .. that i had some mistake on my program .

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -ne 's/£/&pound/g; print $_' file
```

Comment: You should be using the -p flag instead of -n if you're just printing at the end.

    `perl -i.bak -pe 's/£/&pound/g' file`